# What causes VoiceOver to announce empty groups?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

We have the following (simplified) HTML:
*(The real HTML is a little bit more complicated however the `listitem` elements are **exactly** as shown in the snippet below.)*

```html
<div role="list">
  <div role="listitem">Foo</div>
  <div role="listitem">Bar</div>
  <div role="listitem">Baz</div>
</div>
```

As users navigate down the list, VoiceOver announces:

On macOS 10.14 (Mojave):

> Foo, group
> Bar, group
> Baz, group

On macOS 10.15 (Catalina):

> Foo, empty group
> Bar, empty group
> Baz, empty group

The VoiceOver configuration on both macOS seems to be the same so **why does VoiceOver say something different for the same markup?** *(This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/9262) seems to describe a similar situation.)*

Comment: Your closing div tag isn't right, but even when fixed, I can't reproduce this behavior. I suspect something in the surrounding code is messing up the semantics somehow.

Comment: @brennanyoung Oops. Fixed.

Comment: Use an ordered or unordered list and the amount will be properly read. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Listitem_role

Comment: See also this blog article [How to stop VoiceOver saying the word “group”](https://blog.chrisworfolk.com/how-to-stop-voiceover-saying-the-word-group) - but that fix (`<span role="text">` wrapper) isn't working for me in MacOS 11.4 and I'm seeing something similar to the issue in the question but for any non-header element with an `aria-label` but no text content. It looks like MacOS VoiceOver is simply quite unstable in this area.

Answer (score 0):

I also could not reproduce the above issue, but one thing I noticed in one of my code pieces is: if there are line breaks in the code, that also causes the macOS voiceover to announce "Empty Group". I fixed it using aria-hidden="true".

Comment: Not for me, I'm afraid