# Linebreak in a H1 turns the element into a VoiceOver group

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I am using a `<br>` inside a `<h1>` for design reasons eg:

```
<h1>This is a <br>headline</h1>
```

But have noticed that it will turn the element into a **"group"** that VoiceOver reads as separate items, something like:

> Heading level 1 "This is a ... headline" 
> **Group** 3 items 
> "This is a" 
> "headline" 
> "Empty group"

Adding `aria-hidden="true"` or `role="presentation"` attributes to the `<br>` only removes the "empty group" announcement, but VoiceOver still considers the `H1` to be a **"group"**.

Is it possible to have `br` element present inside `h1` without having it announced as **"group"** by VoiceOver?

Comment: Possibly a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204760/use-of-br-and-accessibility) - add aria-hidden to the br: `<br aria-hidden="true" />` or better: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883778/pausing-in-a-screen-reader-for-accessibility) suggesting an aria label - found by [searching SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baccessibility%5D+br)

Comment: @OratorioTangram in your last sentence, you wanted to tell that »`role="presentation"` […] does [*not*] have any effect«?
@mplungjan It would be nice to have this assumption confirmed here as a chosen answer, since none of linked duplicating questions seem do have asked specifically about *preventing* br-induced pauses and none of them addressed specifically VoiceOver.

Comment: @mplungjan Adding `aria-hidden="true"` to the `br` to the br only removes the "empty group" announcement. VO still considers the H1 to be group.

Comment: @myf Correct, it only changes the announcement slightly, but VO still thinks the H1 is a group.

Comment: So that was some improvement. I have re-opened the question

Comment: And this? `<h1 aria-label="This is a headline">This is a <br>headline</h1>`

Comment: @mplungjan it reads the aria-label and then proceeds as before.

Comment: @mplungjan building on that though, this does work but is clumsy - `<h1 aria-label="This is a headline"><span aria-hidden="true">This is a <br>headline</span></h1>`

Comment: And this? `<h1 aria-label="This is a headline" aria-hidden="true">This is a <br>headline</h1>`

Comment: `aria-hidden="true"` would remove the node from the accessibility tree completely, so the `aria-label` will not be announced as long as the `aria-hidden="true"` will be present.

Comment: There is also [What causes VoiceOver to announce empty groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67193091/540955) question with comment citing article that talks about made-up `role="text"`, but it is not clear if doing `<h1><span role="text">foo <br>bar</span></h1>` would help here, really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted to consolidate some of the comments to make it easier to read.

But first a clarification.  The "*group*" announcement is with VoiceOver on a **Mac**.  You do **not** hear "*group*" with VoiceOver on **iOS.**  I don't have a Mac to test these but I did try it on my iPhone.

Regardless of the "group" announcement, my testing is mainly for hearing the heading as one element instead of split in two, although semantically your heading is two elements since you have a `<br>`. This is beside the point of the original question since you were mainly asking how to remove the "group" announcement and not how to read the heading as one element. But nonetheless, here are some testing results for forcing the heading to be read as one. The last example might have a side bonus of eliminating the "group" announcement.

The following ideas have been proposed:

### Original code:

```
<h1>This is a <br>headline</h1>
```

When swiping right with VO on iOS:

- "This is a, Heading level 1"
- "headline, Heading level 1"

NVDA on a PC, using the down arrow to navigate:

- "heading level 1  This is a"
- "heading level 1  headline"

JAWS on a PC, using the down arrow to navigate:

- "heading level 1 This is a"
- "heading level 1 headline"

Other than the "group" announcement on a Mac, this is what I would expect.

### First suggestion:

```
<h1 aria-label="This is a headline">This is a <br>headline</h1>
```

When swiping right with VO on iOS:

- "This is a headline, Heading level 1"
- "This is a headline, Heading level 1"

Since the heading is still two elements (because of the `<br>`) but an `aria-label` is applied (*), you hear the `aria-label` for both parts of the heading.

(*) Note that the `aria-label` overrides child elements **when used properly**, which will be addressed below after all these examples.

NVDA on a PC, using the down arrow to navigate:

- "heading level 1 This is a headline"

There is no second element for NVDA when an `aria-label` is applied because the `aria-label` replaces the contents of all child elements. See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#naming_with_aria-label, in particular:

> When applied to an element with one of the roles that supports [naming from child content](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/names-and-descriptions/#naming_with_child_content), `aria-label` hides descendant content from assistive technology users and replaces it with the value of `aria-label`.

If you follow the [naming from child content](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/names-and-descriptions/#naming_with_child_content) link, a heading is one of the elements.

JAWS on a PC, using the down arrow to navigate:

- "heading level 1 This is a"
- "heading level 1 headline"

The `aria-label` is completely ignored by JAWS and you get the same result as the original code.

### Second suggestion:

```
<h1 aria-label="This is a headline"><span aria-hidden="true">This is a <br>headline</span></h1>
```

When swiping right with VO on iOS:

- "This is a headline, Heading level 1"

There is no second element. The `aria-label` is honored and the `aria-hidden` essentially hides the inner text of the heading itself. `aria-hidden` really should have no effect because the `aria-label` is going to override all child elements (*) as noted above.

(*) Note that the `aria-label` overrides child elements **when used properly**, which will be addressed below after all these examples.

NVDA on a PC, using the down arrow to navigate:

- "heading level 1 This is a headline"

There is no difference for NVDA. The `aria-hidden` has no affect, which is what I expected and which is why I was confused that it affected VoiceOver.

JAWS on a PC, using the down arrow to navigate:

- ""

Nothing is read, presumably because of the `aria-hidden` **and** because JAWS does not honor `aria-label` on a heading, which is part of the (*) comment below. Since JAWS doesn't see the `aria-label` and the contents of the heading are hidden, there is nothing to read.

### Third suggestion:

```
<h1><span role="text">This is a <br>headline</span></h1>
```

When swiping right with VO on iOS:

- "This is a [pause] headline, Heading level 1"

There is no second element because the `role="text"` takes away all child elements and just concatentes the text.  However, VO announces it slightly different than the previous example and has a brief pause between the "a" and "headline",  as if there was a comma between them.

NVDA on a PC, using the down arrow to navigate:

- "heading level 1  This is a"
- "heading level 1  headline"

JAWS on a PC, using the down arrow to navigate:

- "heading level 1 This is a"
- "heading level 1 headline"

Since `role="text"` is not an approved role, there is no difference in this example compared to the original with NVDA or JAWS. However, Apple implemented the role and it's honored with VoiceOver and it does sometimes come in handy as long as you realize it will not have an affect with other screen readers. I've used `role="text"` in production level code with the caveat that support could be taken away at anytime by Apple. But that production code was written 10 years ago and it's still working great.

### (*) comment about using `aria-label` properly

Take a look at "[2.10 Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)", in particular the 7th bullet point:

> Don't use `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` **on any heading elements** because it overrides them on NVDA, VoiceOver and Talkback. **JAWS ignores them. **

So the idea of using an `aria-label` on a heading is **strongly discouraged**.

### One way to have the heading read as one line that is supported by all screen readers AND *might* eliminate the "group" announcement

```
<h1>
  <span aria-hidden="true">
    This is a <br>headline
  </span>
  <span class="sr-only">
    This is a headline
  </span>
</h1>
```

You essentially have two headings. The first one is for the sighted user, which is ignored by the screen reader, and the second one is for the screen reader user, which will not be displayed for the sighted user.

The "sr-only" class is nothing special. It's just a common name to use for "screen reader only" CSS.  You can see more about it at [What is sr-only in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3)

I believe this example will also eliminate the "group" announcement but I don't have a Mac to test that.